# Capturing text from one dynamic text field to another dynamic text field a few frame later in Flash using AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

Basically i have a dynamic text field (txtarea)on a frame and the text inside is inserted by an XML file. this frame also has two buttons allowing you to flick between data in the xml file. I also have a button(btn) going to frame 10 which has another dynamic text field (txtarea2).

What i want to happen is when the user has the desired piece of information in txtarea they press the btn and that information is shown in txtarea2. so basically mirroring the previous dynamic text field.

this is the code i have but it doesnt return anything in the other dynamic text field.

(i have deleted the XML code as it is working)

```
stop();
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, frame5);
function frame5(evt: MouseEvent): void {
gotoAndStop(5);
}

this.storedtxt = txtarea.text

txtarea2.text = this.storedtxt;
```

Ive also tried

```
this.storedtxt = txtarea.text;
txtarea2.text = txtarea.text;
```

What is the correct code for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does txtarea exists in the timeline in the destination frame? If not then

this.storedtxt = txtarea.text

doesn't get anything because txtarea doesn't exists. For the most part, stage display objects get cleared when they are no longer present in the timeline.

When you do

```
function frame5
```

you could store the value of txtarea.txt in a variable in the frame5 function for use later in frame 5.

Try trace statements to check the value of txtarea.txt.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the correct code for this?

Correct way - store data before you leave current frame. From your current logic, you store textfield content instantly user visits frame. And if your field doesn't have a text you will have empty string.

Correct way:

```
function frame5(evt: MouseEvent): void {
    //Store text before user leaves current frame
    this.storedtxt = txtarea.text
    gotoAndStop(5);
}
```

Frame 5 code (I assume you have `txtarea2` TextArea in 5-th frame):

```
txtarea2.text = this.storedtxt;
```